# Adding onto Map instead of overwriting map

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
     for (let i = 0; i < list.result.length; i++) {
        if(mint == MYMAP.get("GRAPE")){
          userDepositInfo.set(list.result[i].person, {GRAPE: list.result[i].info, PUMPKIN: 0, APPLE: 0, ORANGE: 0, PEAR: 0, SHRIMP: 0})
        }
        if(mint == MYMAP.get("PUMPKIN")){
          userDepositInfo.set(list.result[i].person, {PUMPKIN: list.result[i].info})
        }
        if(mint == MYMAP.get("APPLE")){
          userDepositInfo.set(list.result[i].person, {APPLE: list.result[i].info})
        }
        if(mint == MYMAP.get("ORANGE")){
          userDepositInfo.set(list.result[i].person, {ORANGE: list.result[i].info})
        }
        if(mint == MYMAP.get("PEAR")){
          userDepositInfo.set(list.result[i].person, {PEAR: list.result[i].info})
        }
        if(mint == MYMAP.get("SHRIMP")){
          userDepositInfo.set(list.result[i].person, {SHRIMP: list.result[i].info})
        }

      }
```

In this current config the map just over rights it self over and over again

current output:

```
'Joe' => { GRAPE: 1, PUMPKIN: 0, APPLE: 0, ORANGE: 0, PEAR: 0, SHRIMP: 0 },

'Joe' => {PUMPKIN: 2},
'Joe' => {APPLE: 3},
'Joe' => {ORANGE: 4},
'Joe' => {PEAR: 5},
'Joe' => {PEAR: 6},
```

Expected Output

```
'Joe' => { GRAPE: 1, PUMPKIN: 2, APPLE: 3, ORANGE: 4, PEAR: 5, SHRIMP: 6 },
```

My intentions were for the map to keep adding keys onto itself not for it to remove them

Comment: You have to write code to get the current object and then add a property to it.  As you have already discovered `.set()` replaces the current value with an entirely new value - it doesn't add something to the current value unless you write code to do that.

Comment: What are the values in `MYMAP`?

Comment: @Teemu MYMAP is separate. I run this a few times and only need stuff added when mint is set to the value

Comment: @jfriend00 how do I add to it?

Comment: I asked what `MYMAP` contains, depending on its content the task might be very simple.

Comment: @Teemu Its just a string

Comment: It's your question, if you don't want to co-operate, you're no going to get a good answer. The values?

Comment: @Teemu sorry, im not trying to be difficult.  I was just confused. the values are   GR34253
            CRM345
            REWR22
            FDSF32
            GGG242
            43YwE2

Comment: Okay, now we can see, that those values are not related to the keys in `list.result[i].person`, If they were, you'd need a single line in the loop only. Are the values in `MYMAP` constant, or can they vary?

Comment: @Teemu the values are always the same. So if need it could not use MYMAP

Comment: Just for a reference, if you swap the keys and values in `MYMAP` (make it also a simple object instead of Map), the task becomes [much simpler](https://jsfiddle.net/3a5u0khw/).

Comment: I just realized you're probably running this multiple times, [then you need](https://jsfiddle.net/3a5u0khw/1/) to check the existence of the mapped person before creating it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered `.set()` replaces the entire data with a new piece of data.  If, instead, you want to add a new property to an existing object, then you need to get the current object and add a property to it.

Instead of a line like this:

```
userDepositInfo.set(list.result[i].person, {SHRIMP: list.result[i].info})
```

which replaces the value, you can substitute a simple function:

```
function addProperty(person, property, value) {
     let currentData = userDepositInfo.get(person);
     if (currentData) {
          // add or update this property on the existing object
          currentData[property] = value;
     } else {
          // set value with initial object
          userDepositInfo.set({[property]: value});
     }
}
```

And, then use that function like this:

```
addProperty(list.result[i].person, "SHRIMP", list.result[i].info);
```